# JQUERY Highlight on hover

Tags: html, css

I have two tables and they highlight as expected, but I only want the first table's rows to be highlighted, and not the second. How can I achieve this?

http://jsfiddle.net/EZj9T/5/

Comment: What does this have to do with JQuery?

Comment: Then why did you paste the wrong fiddle???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You don't need jQuery for this.**

Add a class to your first table, and only apply styles to that class:

http://jsfiddle.net/EZj9T/12/

```
table.highlight tr:hover                
 { 
     font-weight: bolder; 
     color:black;
 }​
```

---

```
<table border="1" class="highlight">
  ....
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Looks like the first posted fiddle was incomplete.

[Here you have the correct solution](http://jsfiddle.net/EZj9T/11/)

Basically, you just need to give the table you want to highlight a class, like so:

```
<table border="1" class="hightlight">
```

And then in the CSS:

```
.hightlight tr:hover                
 { 
     font-weight: bolder; 
     color:black;
 }​
```

Comment: @Curt. Read the question: _" i only want the first tables rows to be highlighted and not the second is it possible to do thaat?"_

Comment: @gdoron the first fiddle was incomplete. When ambiguous question are asked we risk giving the wrong answer.

Comment: An alternative solution would be to use first-child pseudo class, e.g. table:first-child http://jsfiddle.net/RFEwq/2/

Answer (score 0):

i have changed your sample have a look and see if that is what you need.

it is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Qpirate/EZj9T/13/)

***Edit*** 
Link was incorrect i have put up the proper one

Comment: @gdoron it does in chrome, what browser are you using?

Comment: @ShamariCampbell have a look at my updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Qpirate/EZj9T/14/